# Any way to fix a deleted and readded trunk in Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

We have a subversion repository that has been messed up. Wondering if there are something smart that can be done to fix it.

Basically this is what has happened according to the subversion log:

1. ...old history
2. Delete trunk
3. Create trunk
4. Re-add all files to trunk (with new changes/moves/additions/deletes for good measure)
5. More changes/moves/additions/deletes
6. Even more...

This means we have lost all history between point 1 and 4. Is there anything that can be done here? Or is it best for everyones sanity to just ignore and move on?

Comment: You haven't *lost* any history, it's just more difficult to get at & the link between 4 & 1 has been severed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always recover the old trunk from before the delete an merge the changes from the new trunk on that branch and then make that the nwe trunk

Comment: Problem is that I have zero trust in the merge feature of subversion. Especially when there are moved files involved.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve whatever was there in point 1 and 2.

For that, please follow the below steps.

In the place where 'trunk' was present, you can revert to the version before point 2. Once reverted, this should be committed into SVN again.

By this, all the previous history will be restored without any loss.

Answer (score 0):

Since this involves a change in the URL, you really can't use the merge. What you need to do is to find the location of the old trunk. This isn't too hard to do. You see the Subversion revision number when the old trunk was deleted. It's in the `svn log`. The revision before that is what you want. Let's say revision 12345 is when the old trunk was removed. We're interested in restoring revision 12344.

Let's move the *new trunk* out of the way:

```
$ svn mv -m"Getting the 'new trunk' out of the way" $REPO_URL/trunk $REPO_URL/funky_trunk
```

This keeps the new trunk out of the way, but easily accessible incase you do need something on it.

Now, let's restore the old trunk:

```
$ svn cp -m"Restore the original trunk" -r12344 $REPO_URL/trunk@12344 $REPO_URL/trunk
```

The trunk was deleted in Revision 12345, so I'm copying it from Revision 12344. The `-r12344` is the way the files look at revision 12344. The `@12344` is the structure of the repository at revision 12344.

This will put your trunk back to Step #1 in your list. It's as if the old trunk was never deleted.

Now, you need to do the changes in steps 5, 6, and so forth. You **might** be able to use the merge tool, but only if you use the `--ignore-ancestry` flag. That's because although the old trunk file `$REPO_URL/trunk/dir/foo.txt` and the new trunk file `$REPO_URL/trunk/dir/foo.txt` look the same file to our mere mortal eyes, Subversion sees them as two different files because they have completely different histories. It's what we use to call the *Evil Twin* problem in ClearCase. It's what you get when you version directories too.

---

The real question is why was this done, and why wasn't the perpetrator shot, thrown under a fast moving bus, trampled by elephants, and then fired?

I have a sneaky suspicion that your site is using the *pristine trunk* method. This is where the trunk is never worked on because it's suppose to look like what was whatever the last release. That's what tags are suppose to be for.

This happens because someone is suppose to put the last release on trunk, and doing a merge to trunk can be a messy process if you have a very complicated branching strategy that isn't followed on a regular basis. For example, you're suppose to branch, merge to trunk, and rebranch from the trunk, but most of the time, people branch off the branch. You have a branch of a branch of a branch a few times, you can't merge that back to trunk.

So, what does that person do? They delete trunk, and then copy the branch to the trunk! Hey, the last release is on trunk, and it only took me a few brief seconds, and not a few hours or merging and comparing.

I also get this by your mistrust of Subversion merging. Subversion merging works great if you merge two directly related branches, and don't do a mess of refactoring. (The refactoring issue may be solved in Subversion 1.9 where Subversion will track moves and renames as an actual move and rename and not as a copy and delete).

Subversion merging has problems if you try to merge two unrelated branches, or branches that are distantly related, and that happens if you are attempting to use the trunk for final releases only. Use tags to mark your releases.

There are several strategies for handling branching in Subversion. The *unstable trunk* is used by sites that are heavily involved with continuous integration.

Agile sites prefer making each User Story, Defect, or Task on its own branch, but you have to merge those branches early and often back to some integration branch.

If you insist that trunk must contain only releases, create an *integration branch* and use that for your main work. Branch the integration branch from trunk, and only merge the integration branch to trunk when your finished. All other branching should be from the integration branch.